Iterating in SQL (Redshift) through jinja in a dbt model
I have an sql model which only needs to recalculate some of it's data.
Ex: for cols with date and cost, I need to update cost for August with all records till July End
and to update costs for July need to consider all records <= 30th June. Need to do this for past x months only. Not for all the records in the table.
Tried to write the model in the following way:
{% set num_ite = 6}
{% for i in range(num_ite) %}
    -- sql code with cte
    -- substituting date field with i converted to date
    {% if not loop.last %} Union All {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

This is giving me a runtime error in sql saying there is a syntax error between the last line of the sql and the first line. So it is my assumption that it is not able to successfully loop over.
Any help on this please?

can you share the code it is not possible to say anything without knowing what are you putting in the middle

Will need to see the resulting SQL to see what is going on.  One guess is that you are repeating the cte in each loop and I don’t think you can have a with clause after a UNION ALL

Run dbt compile -s <your_model> and share the results, this is a syntax error
